# 'GO111MODULE' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: go

I have cloned [go repo](https://github.com/grafana/tempo) on windows machine,and am trying to build it(make is installed, v4.3):

> make tempo

It gives me error:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - "*.yaml"
no Go files in ....\tempo
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:51: pipe: Bad file descriptor
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
GO111MODULE=on CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -mod vendor -ldflags "-X main.Branch=fix2308 -X main.Revision=e92189167 -X main.Version=" -o ./bin/windows/tempo-amd64  ./cmd/tempo
'GO111MODULE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [Makefile:63: tempo] Error 1
```

I have set env var GO111MODULE to on.

How should I interpret this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to set environment variables and run a command like `GO111MODULE=on CGO_ENABLED=0 go build` is not supported by Windows. A workaround is to run `make tempo` in "Git Bash" shipped by "Git for Windows". I just had a test and it worked:

```
zeke@my-PC MINGW64 /d/src/temp/tempo (main)
$ make tempo
GO111MODULE=on CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -mod vendor -ldflags "-X main.Branch=main -X main.Revision=e92189167 -X main.Version=main-e921891" -o ./bin/windows/tempo-amd64  ./cmd/tempo
```

**Note**: the output file `./bin/windows/tempo-amd64` does not have the extension `.exe`. Remember to rename this file to add the extension.